# How do we put labels on pie chart arcs - chart.js/vue-chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am using `VueChart js/ chart js` to create a pie chart in my vue project, I would like to show % of data inside the each arcs, how do we do it?
My code in Vue:

```
fillData() {
  this.datacollection = {
    labels: ['T', 'W', 'R', 'B'],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgb(51,122,183)',
          'rgb(226,142,65)',
          'rgb(0,169,157)',
          'rgb(217,83,79)',
        ],
        data: [
          this.tw.length,
          this.w.length,
          this.r.length,
          this.b.length,
        ],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ['#0275d8', '#f0ad4e', '#5cb85c', '#d9534f'],
      },
    ],
  };
  this.options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    devicePixelRatio: 2,
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Arcs state %',
      position: 'bottom',
      fontSize: 20,
    },
  };
},
```

**UPDATE** I tried the plugin recommended by @zb22 and this but it's not working. I did install the plugin through npm

```
 this.options = {
    plugins: {
      labels: {
        render: 'percentage',
        fontColor: ['white', 'white', 'white'],
        precision: 2,
      },
    },
  };
```

I have something like below, and it shows data only when I hove over each arc

[image]

My aim is to display my chart as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart js supported plugins [page](https://github.com/chartjs/awesome) does have a solution for it, it is this plugin [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels) . Make sure you import the module in main.js as  like

```
import labels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
```

and then

```
Vue.use(labels)
```

and update your Vue page :

```
this.options = {
    plugins: {
      labels: [
        {
          render: 'value',
        }
      ],
    },
  };
```

**Update:** A easier to use module/plugin as mentioned by @zb22 is plugin [chartjs-plugin-labels](https://github.com/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels)

If you are using vue just import it in your Vue component like

```
import 'chartjs-plugin-labels';
```

and use it like

```
 this.options = {
    plugins: {
      labels: [
        {
          render: 'percentage',
          fontColor: ['green', 'white', 'red'],
          precision: 2,
        }
      ],
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a plugin to achieve this:
https://github.com/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels

It's well known for this purpose.

This is a [demo](https://emn178.github.io/chartjs-plugin-labels/samples/demo/)

Comment: udpated my question I tried it, but doesn't seem to be working , may be because of Vue js?

Comment: Do we have to import it in main.js?

Comment: try `import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels'`

Comment: That import is for plugin https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels

Comment: Importing like import 'chartjs-plugin-labels'; this works